# Vue three columns of checkboxes in Bootstrap 4

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, v-for

Can anyone help me here with a 3 column layout via vue-js in bootstrap-4. I want to get my checkboxes displaying as 3 columns. The users are in order and I want the order going down the first column, then down the second and finally the third.

```
<div v-for="(user, index) in users">
  <div class="{'controls' : (index % (users.length/3)===0)}">
    <input type="checkbox" :id="'user_'+user.id" :value="user.id" class="form-check-input" v-model="form.checkedUsers">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="'user_'+userr.id">
      <img :src="user.photo_url" class="small-photo mx-2"> @{{ user.first_name }} @{{ user.last_name }}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using the Bootstrap [grid columns](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)?

Comment: The issue is more around the use of the v-for loop and where the div is closed... it closes it on each iteration whereas I really only want it closed at the end of each column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Vue method to group the items into 3 groups using an array "chunk" method. use nested `v-for` to repeat the groups, and then the items in each group. This will put them in 3 columns ordered *top-to-bottom*...

Vue2 controller:

```
  methods: {
    chunk: function(arr, size) {
      var newArr = [];
      for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=size) {
        newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i+size));
      }
      this.groupedItems  = newArr;
    }
  },
```

Markup:

```
<div class="container" id="app">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 py-2" v-for='(g, gIndex) in groupedItems'>
            <form class="form-inline" v-for='(item, index) in g'>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                     {{ item.name }}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** https://www.codeply.com/go/ZaiUsUupsr

---

An **alternate option** is to put them in 3 columns *without* re-iterating the `.row` every 3 items in the loop. All of the checkboxes can go in a single `row`, and they will be in 3 columns ordered *left-to-right*.

**Demo:** https://www.codeply.com/go/3gOvXFzaOw

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div v-for="item in items" class="col-sm-4 py-2">
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" >
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        {{ item.name }}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But that is going to order the results left to right and then down the page rather than down the page and then left to right

Comment: Updated the answer to explain how nesting `v-for` works using a simple chunk method to group the array items.